# Receursivley read lines of a file

Tags: python-3.x

I want to read specific lines of a file each time I run the program.

Say a text file has

```
   line 1
   line 2
   line 3
   line 4
   line 5
   line 6
```

I would like to read every third line of the file, every time I run it.

```
    with open("test.txt", "r+") as f:
         for line in f:
             line = f.readline()
               #do something with line
```

The above code only reads the first line or it just picks which line to read and I want to be specific. Every third line. 
Enumerate does allow for me to read the specific lines but evaluating them one by one is the problem thereafter. 
How do I do it?

Comment: use `for line in f.read().split('\n'):`, **readline** is a generator

Comment: This reads the whole file

Comment: Are you having problems with reading every third line or handling each line?

Comment: I can read each third line and print it. But I don't only want to print it but I want to evaluate it too, say maybe find a certain word from the line. And this, I want to do on each line printed out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example:

```
def _read(file, step, start=0):
    with open(file, "r") as f:
        for line in f.readlines()[start::step]:
            print(line.strip())

_read('test.txt', 3, 2)
```

Output:

```
line 3
line 6
line 9
```

Here is with `class`:

```
class Reader:
    def __init__(self, file_name, mode='r', start=0, step=1):
        self.file = open(file_name, mode)
        self.lines = self.file.readlines()[start::step]
        self.file.close()

    def get_line(self):
        if self.lines:
            return self.lines.pop(0).strip()
        else:
            print('No more lines')

r = Reader('test.txt', start=2, step=3)

print(r.get_line())
print(r.get_line())
print(r.get_line())
print(r.get_line())
print(r.get_line())
```

Output:

```
line 3
line 6
line 9
No more lines
None
No more lines
None
```

Comment: Thank you. Is it also possible to evaluate each line read, individually?

Comment: @Thatile What do you mean by "evaluate each line"? The example is operating on each line individually.